# the definition of a closed map on a functorial scheme in category theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

We define a functorial scheme as in ["Two functorial definitions of schemes"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177933/two-functorial-definitions-of-schemes). I want to define
a *closed map* but we only have the definition of schemes as functors in category theory, so we don't know underlying space. My question is : Can we define a closed map in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, the closed subscheme $V(I)$ can be defined as a subfunctor of $X$ for any quasi-coherent ideal $I$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$. A general closed immersion is is defined as a morphism isomorphic to $V(I) \hookrightarrow X$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The definition of closed immersion can be gave by valuative criterion in category theory. What I want to know is the definition of closed map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one attempt, though perhaps a disappointing one since it's not much different from the usual definition in terms of maps of ringed spaces. $\newcommand{\spec}{\operatorname{spec}}\newcommand\mf\mathfrak$

Say $f:X\to Y$ is a map of schemes (i.e. sheaves on $\mathbf{Ring}^{\mathrm{op}}$ covered by affine schemes). Choose an affine cover $\spec A\to Y$ of $Y$ (exists since $Y$ is a scheme), and let $U:=X\times_Y(\spec A)$ be its pullback to $X$. Let $\spec B\to U$ be an affine cover of $U$. We say that $f$ is a closed map if the ring map $\phi:A\to B$ induced by $\spec B\to U\to\spec A$ satisfies the following property: (*) for any ideal $J\subset B$ and any prime $\mf p\subset A$ containing $\ker(A\xrightarrow\phi B\to B/J)$, there exists a prime $\mf q\subset B$ containing $J$ so that $\phi^{-1}(\mf q)=\mf p$.

Let's unpack a little. Property (*) above is just a translation of what is means for a map $\spec B\to\spec A$ of affine schemes to be closed (assuming I didn't make a mistake). For the rest, keep in mind the following diagram $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\spec B\\
@VVV\\
U @>>> \spec A\\
@VVV @VVV\\
X @>f>> Y
\end{CD}
$\spec B,\spec A$ are affine (open) covers of $X,Y$. Since, topologically speaking, a subspace is closed iff it is in (every member of an) open cover, we're safe to pass to the cover $\spec B\to\spec A$ in order to define closedness of the map $X\to Y$ (e.g. this definition should be independent of the choice of covers and should exactly recover the usual definition when $X,Y$ are themselves affine).

You may worry that all my affine covers are by a single object instead of being of the form $\{\spec A_i\to Y\}_{i\in I}$. This was just to simplify notation. Really, you'd make the above definition with covers like this and then say for every $\spec B_{ij}$ in a cover of $U_i:=X\times_Y(\spec A_i)$ the resulting ring maps $A_i\to B_{ij}$ satisfies (*).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the answer I wanted to know! I'm sorry for lack of knowledge, but could you tell me the answer to the next question? I did not know the fact that a subspace is closed iff it is in (every member of an) open cover. Let $X$ be a topological space, $Y \subset X$ be a a subspace of $X$ and $U = \{U_i:i \in I\}$ be an open cover of $X$ then are $Y$ is closed and  $Y \subset U_i$ for all $i$ equivalent?

Comment: Glad to hear. For this topology fact, if $Y\subset X$ is closed, then clearly $Y\cap U_i\subset U_i$ is closed for every $i$. Conversely, say $Y\cap U_i\subset U_i$ is closed for every $i$. Let $V_i:=U_i\setminus Y=U_i\setminus(Y\cap U_i)$. This is open in $U_i$ and so open in $X$. At the same time $X\setminus Y=\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i$ so $X\setminus Y$ is open in $X$, i.e. $Y$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. Please allow me to ask you the last question. I don't know the proof that if $Y\subset X$ is closed in $X$, then $Y\cap U_i\subset U_i$ is closed in $U_i$. Suppose $S$ is an open(resp. closed) subspace of $X$. Then a subset of $S$ is open(resp. closed) in $S$ if and only if it is open(resp. closed) in $X$. Therefore if $Y\subset X$ is closed in $X$ and $Y\subset U_i$, then $Y$ is closed in $U_i$ so $U_i\setminus Y=U_i\setminus(Y\cap U_i)$ is open in $U_i$ whence $Y\cap U_i\subset U_i$ is closed in $U_i$. But I don't know the proof of $Y\subset U_i$.

Comment: I think you just need to jog your memory on how the subspace topology is defined. If $X$ is a topological space, and $S\subset X$ is any subset, then we give $S$ a topology by saying $T\subset S$ is open iff $T=S\cap U$ for some open $U\subset X$. Equivalently, $T\subset S$ is closed iff $T=S\cap E$ for some closed $E\subset X$. So if $Y$ is closed in $X$, then $Y\cap U_i$ is closed in $U_i$ by definition of the topology on $U_i$.

Comment: I understand. I was unnecessarily confused. Once again, thank you very much for your answers.